# If a commenter says something is wrong but then retracts their statement, should I flag all comments for removal?

Tags: discussion, comments

Let's say a commenter says that an answer doesn't work correctly. Then there is a big discussion with some commenters responding that it does indeed work because of X. The original commenter then says something like "oh yes I was wrong". Should I then flag all these comments for removal? Do they have any value?

Comment: If one commenter mistakenly thought the answer wouldn't work due to Y, others may well think the same thing at first sight at the answer. I think it might well be beneficial to either save a couple of the comments (eg "Doesn't work" "Yes it does because X" "Oh, you're right"), or, even better, prod the answerer or make an edit to clarify. (otherwise, someone may well make the exact same comment with the exact same misunderstanding later)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say yes.

This sounds like basically the comment equivalent of "This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error." If the big discussion was prompted by something that wasn't actually true to begin with, it's unlikely there's anything really useful there.

If you think there *does* happen to be something in the comments that could help someone implement or understand the answer, it couldn't hurt to edit the answer to include it before getting rid of the comments.

Comment: In my specific case, I knew that the original comment was wrong. But I was thinking there might be a situation where I don't know if the comment is wrong or right, and the original commenter might think they were wrong when they were right all along.

Comment: Well, I would say if you're not really sure who's right then flagging the comments as "no longer needed" wouldn't really be appropriate. But if you can see that they just misunderstood something, and the comments got them to understand it, they certainly aren't useful any more _for that person_. But that person's misunderstanding may indicate that whatever aspect of the answer they didn't get at first should be clarified for future readers. I think it's better to do that in the post, though.